# Add 2 list in parameter in JPA using In Query

Tags: java, sql, list, jpa, jpql

I want to pass two list in **jpa query with tuple using IN query**

for eg . `select custid from employee where (custid,name) in ((1,"ford"),(3,"eli"))`

This is normal query and it works, but here i have list of custid and name , so i want to pass list using IN Query.

The query is

```
String sql="select employee.custid from Employee employee

where (employee.id.custid,employee.id.name)  IN (  (:listofcustid , :listofname ))";
```

I am setting parameter as

```
    Query query = em.createQuery(sql); 
    query.setParameter("listofcustid", custidlist);
    query.setParameter("listofname", namelist);
```

But it is not working and giving exception

```
    unexpected AST node: {vector} 
[ select employee.custid from com.dao.Employee  employee where 
(employee.id.custid,employee.id.name)  IN 
((:custIdList0_, :custIdList1_, :custIdList2_),(:nameList0_, :nameList1_, :nameList2_))]
```

But for single List it is working fine

```
  String sql="select employee.custid from Employee employee

    where employee.id.custid IN ( :listofcustid )";

query.setParameter("listofcustid",listofcustid);
```

and when i try to remove the inner braces

```
( :listofcustid , :listofname )
```

it is giving this output with whole exact query with parameters in (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?),

that means it is not taking it as tuple , followed by exception and following line also

`" ORA-00920: invalid relational operator "`

Comment: Why not to use "where employee.id.custid in :listofcustid AND employee.id.name in :listofname"?

Comment: this is not efficient , otherwise we have already used OR also

Comment: @IgorRodriguez: this would be a different query. The first one is equivalent to `where (custid = 1 and name = 'ford') or (custid = 3 and name = 'eli')`, whereas yours is equivalent to `where (custid = 1 or custid = 3) and (name = 'ford' or name = 'eli')`

Comment: and when i try to remove the inner braces  it is giving this output with whole exact query with parameters in (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?) , that means it is not taking it as tuple  , followed by exception and following line also "  ORA-00920: invalid relational operator "

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it supposed to be like this? (opening and closing parenthesis for each named parameter)

```
String sql="select employee.custid from Employee employee

where (employee.id.custid,employee.id.name)  IN ((:listofcustid) , (:listofname ))";
```